# Mono framework setup on Nitrous.io

Tags: mono, installation, cloud, package-managers, nitrousio

What would be easiest way to setup Mono framework on Nitrous.io VM?

Nitrous.io has Autoparts package manager, but it does not contain Mono package yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would have to create an autopart for Mono yourself.
From their website: http://help.nitrous.io/contributing-to-autoparts/

Follow this workflow to contribute an Autoparts package:

1. Fork the Autoparts repo in GitHub.
2. Create a new box in Nitrous.IO.
3. cd to ~/.parts/autoparts
4. Add the fork repo as a a git remote: git
   remote add myfork git@github.com:YOUR-USERNAME/autoparts.git
5. Create the new package file in
   ~/.parts/autoparts/lib/autoparts/packages/mypackage.rb
6. Open a new console tab and check if the package works as expected. parts search
   (see if the new package you created is listed) parts install
   mypackage parts start (if applicable) parts stop parts uninstall
   mypackage
7. Reload the IDE and see if the above actions also works via
   the UI.
8. After you’re confident that the package works, commit and
   push the change to your fork. git commit -m “Added MyPackage.” git
   push myfork master
9. Last, open a pull request via GitHub with a
   descriptive commit message. We will quickly review the part to be
   merged.

Comment: NOTE:  This is now an outdated answer.  Nitrous.io has been replaced by nitrious.io Pro which includes root access and supports apt-get installations.